# EasyMock andReturn() vs andStubReturn()

Tags: unit-testing, easymock

What is the difference between using `andReturn(T value)` vs `andStubReturn(T value)` for EasyMock?

In what situation would you use `andStubReturn()` where `andReturn()` can't achieve the same result?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You use a stub return for a method call on the mock that you expect to happen but aren't otherwise interested in. You use a regular return for a "regular" method call.

Consider the following method:

```
public void someMethod(String arg) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Calling doSomething() on service " 
                       + service.getName().hashCode());
    }

    service.postMessage("{" + arg + "}");

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.info("Finished calling doSomething() on service " 
                      + service.getName().hashCode());
    }
}
```

...where `service` is a mockable field. The `hashCode()` thing in the log statements is contrived, but the point is that your mock needs to respond to any number of calls to `getName()` to avoid an NPE, while you couldn't otherwise care less about it.

When writing an EasyMock based unit test for this method, you'd `andStubReturn()` the call to `getName()` and use a normal `andReturn()` for the call to `postMessage(String)`. When you verify the mock object, it'll only consider the latter and your the test doesn't break if you change the log4j config.

Comment: so let me see if I understand this correctly. Basically andStubReturn() is used for methods that we do not care about for our test for the mock objects , but we're required to mock the return otherwise, the code will not function. The andStubReturn() methods aren't verified by EasyMock; whereas andReturn() methods are verified.

Comment: Hi, will it be the same to use andReturn() with additional expectLastCall().anyTimes()?

Comment: No it is not same. [Anytimes] enables the method to be called any number of times on the mock object, however all such calls will be verified. I.e. if any of the calls doesn't use mock object method then the result will fail.

Comment: @damluar: `andStubReturn()` sets a default return value which is used as a fallback only when regular `.andReturn()` have been used up.  Examples by the EasyMock maintainer:  http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/easymock/message/1069

Answer (score 6):

An additional note for clarity.

If you use .andStubReturn() (or if you use .andReturn(foo).anyTimes()), there will be no minimum expected call count.  So if you set a mock expectation using either of these two, and the mocked method is NOT called, the .verify() call will not assert.

Example that will **NOT** assert when the mocked method isn't called;

```
FooClass myFooClass = EasyMock.createNiceMock(FooClass.class);
EasyMock.expect(myFooClass.someMethod(EasyMock.anyInt()).andStubReturn(true);
EasyMock.replay(myFooClass);

EasyMock.verify(myFooClass);
```

Example that **WILL** assert when the mocked method isn't called;

```
FooClass myFooClass = EasyMock.createNiceMock(FooClass.class);
EasyMock.expect(myFooClass.someMethod(EasyMock.anyInt()).andReturn(true).atLeastOnce();
EasyMock.replay(myFooClass);

EasyMock.verify(myFooClass);
```